# innerHtml doesn't work with ionic 2 pipes, how to?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, innerhtml, angular-pipe

I have a simple pipe that returns some html

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'rating',
    pure: false
})
export class RatingPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): string {
        let stars = "<ion-icon name='star'>" + value + "</ion-icon>";
        return stars;
    }
}
```

the problem is when i use it, i get nothing

```
// this works fine
<p><span innerHtml="{{'<h1>some text</h1>'}}"></span></p>

// if I add a pipe, it doesn't work
<p><span innerHtml="{{variableFromControler | rating}}"></span></p>

// if I add a pipe, it doesn't work
<p><span [innerHtml]="variableFromControler | rating"></span></p>
```

any ideas?

One solution

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser'; // to become DomSanitizer

@Pipe({
    name: 'rating',
    pure: false
})
export class RatingPipe implements PipeTransform {
    sanitizer: any;
    constructor(private domSanitizationService: DomSanitizationService) {
        this.sanitizer = domSanitizationService;
    }

    transform(value: any): string {
        value = parseInt(value);
        let stars = '';

        for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            stars += i <= value ? "<ion-icon class='ion-ios-star'></ion-icon>" : "<ion-icon class='ion-ios-star-outline'></ion-icon>";
        }

        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(stars);
    }
}
```

[documentation on DomSanitizationService](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with this html

```
"<ion-icon name='star'>" + value + "</ion-icon>"
```

because `ion-icon` is a ionic-angular component and it should load via angular2 instead of just using `innerHTML`.

Anyway you should use DomSanitanizeService for your html pipe like this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'rating',
    pure: false
})
export class RatingPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizationService){}
    transform(value: any): string {
        let stars = "<div>" + value + "</div>";
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(stars);
    }
}
```

And in your html you have to use property binding:

```
<span [innerHtml]="text | rating"></span>
```

I would leverage a custom icon wrapper for your case:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-rating-icon',
  template: '<ion-icon name="star">{{rating}}</ion-icon>'
}) 
class RatingIconComponent {
  @Input() rating;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
<ion-rating-icon [rating]="text"></ion-rating-icon>
```

See all examples in **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dQdBVmaPPMdnjL9vQ0bp?p=preview)**

Comment: yes, just found the same solution. I updated my post